# Can I reuse DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, dom

Many of the objects in DOM have state that changes, but some do not seem to.
Suppose you have two select, each with choice A,B,C.  Each select has a current value, but if the values of A,B, C never change, can they be shared? Example:

```
var opt = [
  document.createElement("option"),
  document.createElement("option"),
  document.createElement("option")
];
opt[0].value = 'a';
opt[1].value = 'b';
opt[2].value = 'c';
var select1 = document.createElement("select");
var select2 = document.createElement("select");

for (var i = 0; i < opt.length; i++) {
  select1.appendChild(opt[i]);
  select2.appendChild(opt[i]);
}
```

Comment: A particular DOM element can only be in the document in one place at a time. Appending the element to a new parent implicitly removes it from its previous parent.

Comment: legal? Won't land you in jail for sure :).  I think it's better title as **Can I reuse objects in HTML DOM?**  There is nothing that is legal or illegal about this.  Just saying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like pointy pointed out, appending a dom element to a new parent will remove it from the old one. you can however, clone your options before appending them to the 2nd select:

```js
var opt = [
  document.createElement("option"),
  document.createElement("option"),
  document.createElement("option")
];
opt[0].text = 'a';
opt[1].text = 'b';
opt[2].text = 'c';
var select1 = document.createElement("select");
var select2 = document.createElement("select");

for (var i = 0; i < opt.length; i++) {
  select1.appendChild(opt[i]);
  select2.appendChild(opt[i].cloneNode(true));
}
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(select1);
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(select2);
```